# How to add image and data into firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send/add notification data in database that contains image with some text data so I am not able to add this data in firebase. I tried some code for only data insertion, but it doesn't work and How do I add image in firebase?

I am adding database which is made manually for notification. I want to add further more notifications with image

database

[image]

This is my html form

```
<form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Title</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Image</label>
                                                <input type="image" class="form-control" placeholder="Image">
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Redeem Steps</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="redeem" class="form-control" placeholder="Redeem Steps">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Description</label>
                                                <textarea rows="5" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Here can be your description"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                                        Image 1 <span style="color:red">*</span><!--<input type="file" id="image" name="img1"  required>-->    
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" onclick="submitclick()">Send notification</button>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>
```

this is js file

```
var title=document.getElementById("title");
var redeem=document.getElementById("redeem");
var description=document.getElementById("description");
var image=document.getElementById("image");
var submitBtn=document.getElementById("submitBtn");
var Id=1;
function submitclick(){

    var firebaseref=firebase.database().ref();

    var messagetitle=title.value;
    var messageredeem=redeem.value;
    var messagedescription=description.value;
    //var messageimage=image.value;

    console.log(messagetitle);
    console.log(messageredeem);
    console.log(messagedescription);
    //console.log(messageimage);


    //firebaseref.child("notification").set("vinit");
    //firebaseref.child("notification").set("2");
    //firebaseref.child("notification").set("messagedescription");
    //firebaseref.child("notification").set("messageimage");
    firebase.database().ref('notification/'+Id).set({
        title : messagetitle,
        redeem : messageredeem,
        description : messagedescription
        image : messageimage
      });

      console.log(Id);
Id++;
console.log(Id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot upload image directly into the firebase database. You have to upload the image into the firebase storage first, then you can store the image name/location/downloadUrl in the database if you want. Altough, store the download url is not the best practice.

```
const file = ...
const metadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' }; // or whatever you want
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`images/${file.name}`).put(file, metadata);


uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, snapshot => {
  // If you want to show upload progress, do whatever you want with progress...
  const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED:
      console.log('Upload is paused');
      break;
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING:
      console.log('Upload is running');
      break;
  }
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}, () => {
  // upload finished with success, you can get the download URL
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
    console.log(downloadURL);
  });
});
```

If you want to store the downloadUrl into the databse then you have to store tha downloadUrl into a variable or put the database set into the upload finished callback.
The database set part should work with this way:

```
// The id should foloow your database structure,
// based on your posted image, should look like this:
// `noti_${id}` where the id is a number.
firebase.database().ref(`notification/${id}`).set({
  ...uploadData,
  image: downloadUrl
});
```

Also, I hardly recommend you to use async await to handle promises and use cloud firestore instead of realtime database.

Comment: Thank you and my data also not get inserted into database please help me .please check the code for data insertion

Comment: I've edited the answer :) If that is not wokring an error would be useful

Comment: Actually you *can* store an image in Realtime Database, but you'd have to convert the raw bytes to a string first before doing so.  Typically people might base64 encode it.  But this is a pretty bad idea for larger images.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, you are right, double times, I think is not a good pattern in case of small images, too.